# example that shows that the edge chromatic number may be larger than the maximal degree

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics, discrete-geometry

What is an example that shows that the edge chromatic number may be larger than the maximal degree

∆ ≤ X’(G)

Comment: By [Brooks' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooks%27_theorem) the only examples are odd cycles and complete graphs.

Answer (score 3):

The cycle on three vertices is one example. Any odd cycle will do.